# make python utilize any symbol's input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, symbols

I'm making a code that can translate numbers to piano keys,

***Sorry for the confusion, I meant the ideal output for `"3.14159ABC265"` is `"E1 _ C1 F1 C1 G1 D2 _ _ _ D1 A2 G1"`, however python will give an error when the input has #, \, or something

the codes:

```
numbers = str(input('This code will convert numbers to piano keys, \nnow input any numbers here'))
keys    = str('')

while len(numbers)    ==  str(0):           
    G             =  str('_ ')          
    if numbers[0] == str(0): G='B1 '        
    if numbers[0] == str(1): G='C1 '        
    if numbers[0] == str(2): G='D1 '
    if numbers[0] == str(3): G='E1 '
    if numbers[0] == str(4): G='F1 '
    if numbers[0] == str(5): G='G1 '
    if numbers[0] == str(6): G='A2 '
    if numbers[0] == str(7): G='B2 '
    if numbers[0] == str(8): G='C2 '
    if numbers[0] == str(9): G='D2 '
    keys          += G              
    numbers       =  numbers[1:len(numbers)]    

print(keys)
```

This code is already working, but not when the input has \, # or something. I've searched for a while but didn't found an answer.

By the way I think python should have an option to disable the differences between numbers and strings in a short code like this XD

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ord` to turn any characters into numbers (based on [ASCII values](https://www.asciitable.com/)), then use division and remainder to map the numbers into piano key numbers and scales, and then use `chr` to turn key numbers into alphabets. Here's a one-line example:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(lambda c: chr(ord('A') + int((ord(c) - ord(' ')) % 7)) + str(int((ord(c) - ord(' ')) / 7)), input()))
3.14159ABC265
'F2 A2 D2 G2 D2 A3 E3 F4 G4 A5 E2 B3 A3'
>>>
```